# Why is the week_day API not working on a model method in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

**model**

```
class Attn(Timestamp):
    dt = models.DateField()

    @property
    def saturday(self):
        return self.dt__week_day == 7
```

I am trying to find the number of entries in the model that was a Saturday. I found the API from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#week-day). So I made a list comprehension as following.

**view**

```
len([1 for i in attns if i.saturday])
```

When I run the view it shows `AttributeError`.

```
'Attn' object has no attribute 'dt__week_day'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Attn(Timestamp):
    dt = models.DateField()

    @property
    def saturday(self):
        return self.dt.weekday() == 7

>>> sum(1 for i in attns if i.saturday)
```

Comment: can you try replacing `dt__week_day` with `dt__day`. hope this helps

Comment: According to the reference page I have provided it says Saturday is 7. But If I am using `day` shouldn't Saturday be 5?

Comment: Btw, it doesn't work. Gives me the same AttributeError.

Comment: Also, more pythonic and idiomatic way to check is: `any(i.saturday for i in attns)`. It also has better performance as it will stop scanning the queryset/list of `attns` at the first occurence of Saturday.

Comment: I don't want it to stop scanning after the first Saturday. I want the number of all Saturdays that has an entry in the model.